# Multiple Date Object comparisons not working as expected

Tags: javascript

Trying to figure out why my Date Object values are not comparing correctly. The same 'GREATER than' string is being appended to both 'review-full-review-comment-wrap' blocks...Is my method of comparing the dateObjects values correct?

```
<div class="review-full-review-single-wrap">
    <div class="review-full-stars">
        <span class="review-full-timestamp">
            <time itemprop="datePublished" datetime="2014-07-29T11:25:47-07:00">July 29, 2014</time>
        </span>
    </div>

    <div class="review-full-review-comment-wrap"></div>
    ////*Append LESS THAN*////
</div>

<div class="review-full-review-single-wrap">
    <div class="review-full-stars">
        <span class="review-full-timestamp">
            <time itemprop="datePublished" datetime="2015-05-05T05:50:05-07:00">May 5, 2015</time>
        </span>
    </div>

    <div class="review-full-review-comment-wrap"></div>
    ////*Append GREATER THAN*////
</div>

function runProgram(){

    var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("review-full-timestamp");

    for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
        var timeElems = document.getElementsByTagName("time");
        var dateString = Date.parse(timeElems[i].innerHTML);
        var dateObj = new Date(dateString);
        var startDate = "May 6, 2015";
        var startDateObj = new Date(startDate);
    }

    if(dateObj > startDateObj){
        $('.review-full-review-comment-wrap').append('<p>GREATER than</p>');
    } else {
        $('.review-full-review-comment-wrap').append('<p>LESS than</p>');
    }

}
runProgram();
```

Comment: Your loop structure is broken. You don't handle the two elements separately, you loop over them and fetch the `dateObj` from the last of them, then you *append the same comparison result to all wrap elemnts*.

Comment: i think you need to use `getDate() getMonth() getYear()` and create a new `Date` object with these arguments

Comment: Despite what others are saying here, rest assured that the `dateObj > startDateObj` expression works correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comment @Bergi made above: Here is the correct function

```
var startDate = new Date( 'May 6, 2015' );
$( '.review-full-review-single-wrap' ).each( function( i, e ) {
    var dateObj = new Date( Date.parse( $( e ).find( '.review-full-timestamp > time' ).attr( 'dateTime' ) ) );
    var div = $( e ).find( '.review-full-review-comment-wrap' );
    if ( dateObj.getTime() >= startDate.getTime() ) {
        div.append( '<p>dateObj is GREATER than startDate</p>' );
    } else {
        div.append( '<p>dateObj is LESS than startDate</p>' );
    }
} );
```

Comment: Glad you could figure it out yourself :-) However, I think you want `>` instead of `>=`, and you can easily omit the `.getTime()` on both sides, it's implicitly called when comparing date objects anyway.

Answer (score 0):

See [getTime()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime)

Consider the following example based on your code:

```js
        var dateString = Date.parse('10-23-2015');
        var dateObj = new Date(dateString);
        var startDate = "May 6, 2015";
        var startDateObj = new Date(startDate);

        if(dateObj.getTime() > startDateObj.getTime()){
            console.log('cool');
        }
```

This outputs

> cool

As you can see, `10-23-2015` **is** bigger than `May 6, 2015`.

Comment: I know how to output a value but adding the getTime() function stills yields the initial result where the "same" greater than string is being appended to both blocks

Comment: What is a 'same greater than string' ?

Comment: in the if condition where the program is to append, the "GREATER than" string is being appended to both blocks. I am trying to modify the code so that the LESS than string is appended to the block if the dateObj value is less than startObj value.. and vice versa

Comment: Edited my answer as I have no clue what you are getting at. The example works as intended

Comment: thanks your example does work- I think I am not looping correctly as Bergi mentioned above

Answer (score -1):

Try adding `.getTime()` to each date object , push date values to an array , use `Array.prototype.some()` to determine if either of `time` elements `html` parsed to `Date` objects is greater than `startDateObj`

```js
function runProgram() {
  var times = [];
  var startDate = "May 6, 2015";
  var startDateObj = new Date(startDate).getTime();
  var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("review-full-timestamp");
  for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    var timeElems = document.getElementsByTagName("time");
    var dateString = Date.parse(timeElems[i].innerHTML);
    var dateObj = new Date(dateString);
    times.push(dateObj.getTime());
  }

  if (times.some(function(time) {
    return time > startDateObj
  })) {
    $('.review-full-review-comment-wrap').append('<p>GREATER than</p>');
  } else {
    $('.review-full-review-comment-wrap').append('<p>LESS than</p>');
  }

}

runProgram();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="review-full-review-single-wrap">
  <div class="review-full-stars">
    <span class="review-full-timestamp">
            <time itemprop="datePublished" datetime="2014-07-29T11:25:47-07:00">July 29, 2014</time>
        </span>
  </div>

  <div class="review-full-review-comment-wrap"></div>
  ////*Append LESS THAN*////
</div>

<div class="review-full-review-single-wrap">
  <div class="review-full-stars">
    <span class="review-full-timestamp">
            <time itemprop="datePublished" datetime="2015-05-05T05:50:05-07:00">May 5, 2015</time>
        </span>
  </div>

  <div class="review-full-review-comment-wrap"></div>
  ////*Append GREATER THAN*////
</div>
```

Comment: I realized that in my first 'review-full-timestamp' block the date was greater that the 'startdateObj' value. Can you edit your code above to make the July 29, 2014 instead of 2015 and see if it stills runs correctly?

Comment: you updated the variable - the edit to the date should be made to the first time tag value... not the variable date

Comment: @Jgunzblazin Is requirement to determine if `startDateObj` is greater than either of `time` element date ?

Comment: opposite, it's to check if dateObj is greater startDateObj. But I believe the issue is not in my date comparisons at Bergi mentioned above- I need to figure out whats wrong w my loop

Comment: @Jgunzblazin To clarify , what is `startDate` ? What should `time` elements `html` be ? Yes, `for` loop incorrect. Updated post, though want to confirm what dates should be

Comment: @Jgunzblazin See updated post . Is requirement to append greater than or less than to each `.review-full-review-comment-wrap` element ? , or append greater than or less than only once ?

Comment: greater than or less than once

Comment: Does `js` at post return expected results ?

Comment: the time values are loaded from another function- I am using JS to look those values and compare them, the append